# Simple web server using C programming

Tags: c, web-services, webserver

I need to develop a web server using c in Linux. Using that we need to start and configure services. is their any help like pseudo code or sample programs like that.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on those services :) Also is this an academic project ?

Comment: its not an academic project. actually i am doing an embedded web service.. but i am new to this so i started with a simple one.

Comment: services like starting Apache and configuring it using this webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Server-Example.html

This is a simple multi-user web server built in C. I had to do one of these last year for a class, and I find it quite cool, though a little bit frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache HTTP server, the world's most popular HTTP server, is written in C.  Its documentation, and source downloads are located [here](http://httpd.apache.org/)